# css issue: extra white space on the right of all my content

Tags: css

I'm posting my issue here because I can't find the problem by my own.

I'm building this website: http://www.karlienfabre.be/basmicro , at this time it's possible to scroll horizontally because there is a lot of white space at the right. I do not want this white space, I don't want that you can scroll horizontally.

I think it is something with the section nav

If there is a css-hero who can help me...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i dont see the problem. which browser?

Comment: I checked your site in the latest Chrome and Firefox and don't see the issue :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski The issue is that you can scroll left. `body` has `overflow: hidden` but you can still scroll with middle mouse key, of by dragging on tablet. Then you will see huge white area.

Comment: What's the problem with the section !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `section#twitter` slider. It's very wide that's why it expands the body width too. Try this simple fix:

```css
#twitter .container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: So I was looking at the wrong place. Thanks! :-) #happystudent

Comment: You are welcome. The way I looking for in case of such kind of issues, is that I remove nodes (Delete key) one by one in developer tools, and see if the issues remains. This way you can easily localize the problem.

Comment: That's a method to remember!

Comment: Yes, and you can revert node back if you need with `Ctrl+Z`.